# dialogs must be user-initiated - RadUpload control of telerik for silverlight 4

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0, telerik

I am upgrading my application from silverlight 3 to silverlight 4 and using latest telerik binaries which is for silverlight 4, I have one issue in RadUpload.

When `RadUpload.ShowFileDialog();` method called it will through the error as follows

> System.Security.SecurityException: Dialogs must be user-initiated.

Can anyone help me out in this issue?

Thanks in Advances
Bhushan Deshmukh

Comment: You are calling this method from a button click somewhere?

Comment: yes, It is fired from button click. You have any solution.

Answer (score 1):

I've given up on Telerik controls, but the one thing that they are great at is responding to the forums on their site. I'm sure if you moved this to the Telerik site you'll receive an answer within one or two days, if one is not posted already.

http://www.telerik.com/community/forums/silverlight/upload/dialogs-must-be-user-initiated.aspx